# How to change ListView to RecyclerView in Android Studio?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I don't know how to use RecyclerView to replace ListView. Anyone can help me? Thank you. I find out so many resources in the different online platform but I don't know how to change my code. When I trying to alter my code, it doesn't work.

Code is in the following:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        String email = c.getString("email");
                        String address = c.getString("address");
                        String gender = c.getString("gender");

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                        String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                        String home = phone.getString("home");
                        String office = phone.getString("office");

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        contact.put("email", email);
                        contact.put("mobile", mobile);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email",
                    "mobile"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                    R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

HttpHandler.java

```
public class HttpHandler {

    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public HttpHandler() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="hk.edu.ouhk.android.jsonparsing.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mobile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#686868"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_? what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

as you seems to have no problem getting data from url and you successfully have made an Arraylist from the data

steps to follow now
 1. add recyclerview to xml of your activity
 2. make a layout how you want to display data in recyclerview items
 3. then you need to make an adapter that takes data you provide and binds it to 
  recycler view
 4. then add adapter to your recycler view

I am attaching simple recycler view which I made a while ago for me. It is simple and self explanatory. Otherwise you can comment I will explain it more

```
Main Activity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<String> moviesList;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    moviesList=new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerAdapter=new RecyclerAdapter(moviesList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    moviesList.add("Kapil");
    moviesList.add("Kapil");
    moviesList.add("Kapil");
    moviesList.add("Kapil");
    moviesList.add("Kapil");
    moviesList.add("Kapil");
    moviesList.add("Kapil"); }
 }



RecyclerAdapter in this we are creating custom viewholder for us
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> 
  {
public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> moviesList) {
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
}

ArrayList<String> moviesList;
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder= new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.rowTextView.setText(String.valueOf(position));
holder.textView.setText(moviesList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return moviesList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView,rowTextView;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        rowTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
    }
  }
 }

 This is layout for the item which I want to show in recycler view
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Just pass your array list to it. Like i did

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create RecyclerViewAdapter with ViewHolder pattern, and just simply replace ListView to RecyclerView

Comment: But I don't know how to write the ViewHolder. Can you give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: it is pretty simple, just read few post for beginners like this https://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/